# Игнорируется параметр maxlength

Tags: html, css

```
<form>
<input class = 'reg' id = 'log' placeholder = 'Логин' style = 'display:none'  maxlength="16"></input>
<input class = 'reg' id = 'pass' placeholder = 'Пароль' style = 'display:none' type = 'text' maxlength="10"></input>
<input class = 'reg' id = 'rep' placeholder = 'Повторите пароль' style = 'display:none' type = 'password'></input>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.reg {
position: absolute;
padding: 10px;
margin-left: 300px;
border-radius:10px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc inset;
transition:500ms all ease;
width: 150px;
}

.reg:hover {
width: 180px;
}

#log {
margin-top: 150px;
}

#pass {
margin-top: 200px;
}

#rep {
margin-top: 250px;
}
```

- `Position:absolute` мне нужен, т.к. элемент я помещаю на canvas. В
  чем собсна проблема.
- `style='display:none'` на определенном уровне преобразовывается в
  `style='display:block'`

Параметр `maxlength` тупо игнорируется, не смотря на `maxlength="12"` я могу вводить любое количество символов. В чем проблема, что мешает?

Заранее благодарен за ответ)

Comment: btw у меня код из вашего примера работает и с неодиночными тегами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input`  - одиночный тег (не закрывается) :

```css
.reg {
position: absolute;
padding: 10px;
margin-left: 300px;
border-radius:10px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc inset;
transition:500ms all ease;
width: 150px;
}

.reg:hover {
width: 180px;
}

#log {
margin-top: 150px;
}

#pass {
margin-top: 200px;
}

#rep {
margin-top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input class = 'reg' id = 'log' placeholder = 'Логин'  maxlength="16">
<input class = 'reg' id = 'pass' placeholder = 'Пароль' type = 'text' maxlength="10">
<input class = 'reg' id = 'rep' placeholder = 'Повторите пароль' type = 'password'>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо, забыл об этом, слишком давно не писал сайты)

Comment: Я не вполне уверен, что это послужило причиной проблемы автора. Ну и советую одиночные теги все таки закрывать <input />, оно конечно итак работать будет с нормальным доктайпом

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, да вы можете советовать что угодно, но правильно писать одиночные теги так как они задуманы разработчиками!

Comment: @Elena, а почему Вы решили, что это Вы пишете так как они задуманы разработчиками, а не я?

Comment: @Elena на самом деле и так и так можно, просто самозакрывание - это такой синтаксический сахар чтобы сделать более xml-like

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, на самом деле изучите html5!

Comment: @Elena, очень мило) Вот источник по которому я изучаю html: w3c спецификация. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags. Обратите внимание на пункт 6. Если Вы не в курсе, то спецификация - это то как задумали разработчики. Мой аргумент за самозакрывающиеся теги связан с соображениями совместимости с XML спекой, которые не то чтобы практичны в большинстве случаев, но иногда всплывают. Ах что я вам про спецификации, Вы по какому источнику html5 учили-то?